# WP CLI command to delete products from a specific category?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, command-line-interface, wp-cli

While the command to

```
DELETE ALL CATEGORIES IS - wp term list product_cat --field=term_id | xargs wp term delete product_cat
```

AND

```
DELETE ALL THE PRODUCTS IS - wp post list —field=ID —post_type=product | xargs wp post delete —force
```

what would be the command to select products from a specific category/categories and delete them.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You use the category specifier `--category="your category"`.

For example `wp post delete $(wp wc product list --user=1 --format=ids --category=64) --force`.